# Redirect multiple category URLs to one category URL using Regex

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

Struggling to understand the Regex needed for this form reading several forum posts. Hoping someone who's an expert can provide a quick answer to this.

```
/shop/accompaniments/product-name-a/
/shop/bbq/product-name-b/
/shop/bundles/product-name-c/
```

All to redirect to

```
/product/product-name-a/
/product/product-name-b/
/product/product-name-c/
```

Thanks

Anthony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)shop/accompaniments(.*)$ /$1product$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)shop/bbq(.*)$ /$1product$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)shop/bundles(.*)$ /$1product$2 [R=301,L]
```